# Using 2 redundant Servers to Netboot Devices over network

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhcp-server, netboot

Is it possible, and how would you go about doing the following.

I have 2 Servers ( 1 is primary and other acting as backup) and many devices connected to these servers. I would like to set up Netbooting ( perhaps using PXE,DHCP or other method).Specifically I need to use IP/Port address because these devices could be replaced(so the physical MAC address is out of the question).

Some questions/possible issues:

- How can you have both Servers pointing to a single IP address ( in other words the device)
- Netbooting has to be able to happen from whichever server is Primary ( smart logic will need to be built in( either in the device to know which Server to look for, or most likely at the Server itself)

Answer (score 0):

DHCP failover is possible with implementations like ISC dhcpd. Because they need to communicate they necessarily will be different IP addresses. However they will coordinate the response to broadcast requests.

Or, virtualize one DHCP instance. Start it somewhere else in the event of a host failure.

Comment: Can you expand on the second option ( the one that does not require different IP addresses for communication)?

Comment: Any logic, high level explanation that will help me understand and point me in the right direction on what to look for, and experiment will help.